# API error while trying to Add Row to Data Extension

Tags: api, error, fuel-sdk, dataextensions

I have the Error Message : **Exception occurred during [Create:ProcessCreateBatch] ErrorID: 1525450278** when trying a new row in a Data Extension with the API.

The API is called using Fueld SDK https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-PHP

Our workflow is working properly for registering Subscriber and adding them to list(s). But when sending data to a DataExtension, it does fail.
Below is the output of the callback from the API:

```
ET_Post Object
(
    [status] => 
    [code] => 200
    [message] => 
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [StatusCode] => Error
                    [StatusMessage] => Errors Occurred
                    [OrdinalID] => 0
                    [ErrorCode] => 2
                    [NewID] => 0
                    [Object] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [PartnerKey] => 
                            [ObjectID] => 
                            [CustomerKey] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                            [Properties] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Property] => Array
                                        (
                                            // Removed before posting

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [ErrorMessage] => Exception occurred during [Create:ProcessCreateBatch] ErrorID: 1525450278
                )

        )

    [request_id] => 
    [moreResults] => 
)
```

I could not find anything explaining this error.
Any help to spot the error would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: Have you found the solution yet?

Comment: I have moved the Data Extension from Shared Data Extension to current B.U. Data Extension